# why perform null check in Groovy using 'null'

Tags: groovy, null

I am working on xRay integration with JIRA, and xRay will complain if the label is a null instance. So in the Jenkins pipeline, there is following code to check null instance

```
if (environment != 'null') {
    envPlatformArray.add(environment)
}
if (platform != 'null') {
    envPlatformArray.add(platform)
}
```

I am considering the check of none instance should be performed like following:

```
if (environment != null)
{
    ...
}
```

or something like

```
if (environment){
    ...
}
```

But after debugging on Jenkins, I am surprised to find the existing code work as expected. I don't know if I missed something or it is by default the correct way to check something is not null should be using

```
instanceObj != 'null'
```

Sorry if this has been asked already I will close it if that is the case. Thanks for help.

Comment: looks like `'null'` is used as a String constant with some special meaning

Comment: Hi is that only applies to null check in Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any special meaning of `'null'` String constant in Groovy. Neither the Groovy compiler.

```
println null == null
println null == 'null'
println 'null' == null
println 'null' == 'null'
println !!null
println !!'null'
```

prints:

```
true
false
false
true
false
true
```

I used https://groovyconsole.appspot.com to run code

Looks like the `environment` and `platform` vars are turning from `null` to `'null'` somewhere up the pipeline.